# Is there a way to prevent conflicting css files in Laravel within the public folder

Tags: css, laravel

I have added css links with the `asset()` helper within my master file but they seem to bring about style conflicts. I would like to find a way of including all my css files without the conflict

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/frontend_css/style.css')}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= 
      {{asset('css/frontend_css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/frontend_css/font- 
      awesome.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/frontend_css/animate.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/frontend_css/sina-nav.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/frontend_css/pdt.css')}}">
```

Comment: Place your `custom css` file in last.

Answer (score 3):

The order in which you import your stylesheets is important - each stylesheet you add will override the previous variables if applicable, so put your main, custom CSS last to override the others.

e.g:

stylesheet-a.css

```
body {
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
}
```

stylesheet-b.css

```
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

On your imports:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/stylesheet-a.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/stylesheet-b.css')}}">
```

This will produce a background of yellow and text that is black. If you import it the other way around, you will have a red background with black text.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks let me try it out

Comment: @JordanRob let me know if you're still stuck and maybe we can try something else!

Comment: Its also worth mentioning that specificity also has weight in which styles are overriding https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: @party-ring still stuck just resorted to changing tags with the same class names  in the different files , too tedious though